# Personal electronics tool kit

Tags: kits, tools

What are the items you have in your personal electronics tool kit?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Most important tool:

- A quality **soldering iron**.  Mine's a Weller.  Those Radio Shack pencil irons are useless, and will only make life more difficult.
- A **wet sponge** for cleaning the iron tip, several **tips** for the iron.
- Both **desoldering braid** and a **solder sucker**.
- Plenty of **60/40 solder**, the silver bearing stuff doesn't flow nearly as well.  A well stocked junkbox is extremely important.  The more components you have to hand, the faster you can work.
- A good **digital multimeter**, I love my Fluke.  Add to that a good **analog multimeter**, digital meters offer no sense of change over time.
- A **dual channel 100MHz oscilloscope** (mine's a tektronix mainframe that I scavenged).
- Good **lighting**!  A **third-hand rig** or similar to hold parts and boards that are being soldered.
- A **spectrum analyzer** is very useful for radio work.
- A **function generator**.
- A sharp pair of **flush cutting nippers**.
- Several spools of different coloured **20 gauge hookup wire**.
- Some people keep flux to hand, but I've never found I needed it.
- Assorted scraps of printed circuit board, or **strip board** - breadboards are very finicky and can add circuit-killing parasitic capacitance.
- The absolute best tool I've found for cutting PCB is a **jeweler's saw**.  You can buy them from Contenti, and aren't very expensive.  I've never seen anything use produce a better or faster cut.

I think that covers the bulk of it, it may seem like a lot of stuff but it's mostly small stuff.  An **LCR meter** is handy, too.  I have a foredom flexshaft, it's kind of like a **Dremel** but more powerful and higher quality. They're not cheap machines, but are a real life saver for modifying circuit boards.

Comment: I've got one of the digitally controlled soldering irons like they sell at Sparkfun (Aoyue, I think).  Best tool purchase I've made.

Comment: I've just bought a ZD-916 temperature controlled soldering iron from Maplin and the difference between that and my cheapo pencil iron is amazing. Suddenly I can almost solder properly :)

Comment: Add a power supply to that list and you're golden.

Comment: +1 for a good answer but especially for the analog multimeter.  I have none currently, only a couple digital ones.  Oh sure, my brain is fast at interpreting numbers, but you just can't beat a swinging needle when monitoring certain things.

Comment: I went through your answer and added bullet-points, as it was really hard to follow without them.

Comment: What do you have against "radio shack" soldering irons?

Comment: Would you please provide you opinion about drills too?

Answer (score 11):

[image]

- [Harbor Freight multimeter](https://www.harborfreight.com/electrical/electrician-s-tools/multimeters-testers/7-function-digital-multimeter-63759.html).  They actually work quite well.  RS has some slip-over test lead IC-hooks that work with the bundled test leads, totally worth the extra cost.  More expensive meters are better, but these are accurate enough (esp. for digital work: is it high? is it low?  it's cheaper than a logic probe!) and small enough to go in a small tackle/toolbox, and if something goes wrong it's easy to replace.  The transistor tester (shown below)
  [image]
  saved me when I picked up some 2N2222's at RS and discovered that the package had the pinout backwards.  Seriously, even if you have a nicer meter, you *will* find uses for one of these.
- **Lots of IC-hook wires**.  Those things are fantastic, and are great for probing and prototyping.  You can never have too many of those.  I prefer these over alligator clips.
- Small/jewelers screwdrivers.
- Wire stripper.
- Small needle-nose pliers.
- Analog o-scope that was a cast-off from school.
- RS soldering irons.  Honestly though, it's not worth getting the RS.  Get a good iron.  And solder wick, not that silly solder sucker bulb thing.  I think this is the area I regret the most in my toolkit.  I've used the small pencil iron three times and I botched a board with it because it didn't get hot enough.
- Arudino + Protoshield.  Nice, small little prototyping platform.
- 6500K desk lamp lighting.  Really, the daylight color helps.  Very bright.
- Plastic compartment boxes for holding parts.

Comment: Your link goes to the wrong product

Comment: I also use the Transistor hFE tester. I fixed your link and added pics.

Answer (score 8):

1. 1k, 10k resistors, i rarely need
   other values, maybe 100s if I have
   LEDs.
2. caps, 4.7uF, 1000pF, .1uF
3. PICs, just some PICs, i think I have
   some pic16F876As, but I have access
   to three others also.
4. LEDS, a few cheap ~10mA LEDs
5. FLash memory, I never know when my
   project will need memory, I keep
   simple ATMEL memory, I can give a
   part number if wanted.
6. ft232R, never know when I want some
   USB connectivity.
7. I have other random parts, but they
   probably cycle pretty constantly.

I try to get a professor or my boss at work to buy my components, I do not tinker a large amount at home, but build little projects for my professor, or students in the class I help teach, to use, or I will build little projects to speed up a task at my job.

Comment: I will admit, at work I have one cheap o-scope, at school I can get a hold of some nice equipment, but rarely need it. The most important thing for me at school is use of a current-limited power supply. At work we use batteries in our devices, so stuff blows up when we mess up. Nothing like shorting a car battery.

Answer (score 8):

A couple of people have asked me about tools
so I put together this list (below). I will put
it on my site soon. If you think you may want
to do SMD I would invest in a better iron 
than listed below (also a good light and
a magnifier). My SMD tool recommendations
are at http://tinyurl.com/5foeou

### Tools

- (1) Weller WESD51 Soldering Station
  or Hakko 936ESD (diy list)
- (1) Well WSA350  Weller Smoke Absorber
- (5) WSA350F filter 3-pack
- (1) Panavise 308 Base Mount
- (1) Panavise 305 Base
- (1) Panavise 366 Jaws
- (1) Cooper Tools "Xcelite" 170M cutter
- (1) Ideal T-6 16-26AWG wire stripper
- (1) Ideal T-8 8-16AWG wire stripper
- (1) X-Acto x3201 No. 1 Knife
- (1) X-Acto x411  No. 11 Fine Point Blade
- Needle Nose Pliers, narrow tip

### Supplies

- Kester 24-6337-6422 Solder
- Kester 2331-ZX Flux
- Chemtronics 5-25L Solder Wick
  Could add Chemtronics 10-25L Solder Wick
- 3M 2214 Wrist Strap
- 3M 8214 Anti-static Matt
- 5854/7 BL005 100ft 24AWG Blue Wire, Teflon
- 299 SV005   24AWG Bus Wire
- Extech EX330 Multimeter
  or Extech XTC-MM560 (sdiy list)

### Custom circuits (not kits)

- 169P84WE (unclad) Vector board
- Vector T42-1 Clips
- Vector K24A Push pins
- 299/3 SV005 30AWG Bus Wire
- Extech Power Supply 382213

Answer (score 6):

Tool wise I have: Multimeter, probe, pocket oscilloscope from seed studio, solder iron, screw drivers, and other various hand tools.

Bench wise I have: tektronix oscilloscope (from school), programmable power supply(from school), function generator

Component wise: Too many to list here. I am one of those people that stores love to see coming. I see something and think to myself "I might be able to use that later" and so I stock up in bulk. Or my neighbors throw out stuff and I take it and rip parts off it (my wife hates that). She thinks I could be on that show called "Hoarders" but for electronic components. Then I lucked out because my school upgraded their labs, and my professor gave me everything they had because the school was just going to throw them out!

Comment: I'm a big advocate of buying components in bulk.  They have near infinite shelf life(except for electrolytics), and in bulk the price can halve.  When I buy transistors I tend to buy 75 or 100 at a time.  When I do that, I pay less than half per transistor, and I spread the shipping across more components.

Comment: I always buy in bulk from mouser/digikey(normally mouser) for parts, our school also does a weekly order that I can place parts on and have them free of shipping.

Answer (score 5):

I make sure I have a 1/8" stereo jack on a length of wire so I can plug my breadboard projects straight into my computers audio input. I also have some paperclips, that I normally use for bending into little brackets, that can hold various strange shaped components onto the breadboard, i.e little piezo buzzers or speakers. 
And last but not least, Blue Tac, I can't stress enough how many times it's helped me out in a tight spot, it's useful for all sorts, not to mention holding wires in place whilst soldering.
I also have a lamp, it's an eco-friendly 2.5w super massive LED thingy. It's got a swan neck, it's really bright and at £20 from Ikea it's a darn site cheaper than a proper technicians desk lamp.

Jim.

Comment: stereo input into your speaker? Now that's making due with the bare essentials! lol

Answer (score 4):

Here are some of the tools I find myself using most often:

- Weller WES51 soldering iron
- Panavise Jr.
- Fluke 87V multimeter
- PHT-PYT-4 wire strippers (*don't* buy the cheap chinese knockoffs. Mine were unusable.)
- Rigol DS1052E oscilloscope (somewhat expensive, but even as a relative beginner it's been an invaluable learning tool for showing what's actually going on with the voltage levels inside a circuit.)
- Cooper Tools "Xcelite" 170M cutter
- Elexp 060210 long nose pliers (I find myself using these constantly. Best $2 I ever spent.)
- Soldapullt deluxe
- Scotch tape for holding components in whilst I'm soldering them on the underside of the board.

I use a 12V computer fan hooked up to my three output variable power supply to dissipate solder fumes. Seems to work fine for now.

Answer (score 3):

- A pencil (and sharpener). Molten tin won't stick to the carbon of the pencil, so you can use it to open a solder pad or solder bridge. It is in the same category as desoldering braid and a solder sucker.
- I like to use one small and cheap breadboard for soldering. It holds pins nicely in place while I solder them. I use it only for soldering to prevent flux and resin from ending up on other components. Same category as a third-hand rig.
- Antistatic foam to keep IC's safe.
- A drawer full of old power supplies (SMPS, that came with telephones, monitors, network equipment, ... at various voltages and currents) saved from the junk yard.
- Order components in bulk: 10, 50, 100, 500+ pcs. prices can drop incredibly if you find the right shops.
- Couple universal heat sinks and mounting material.
- Pin headers, lots of them. I often push the pins out to reuse them by pushing them eg. into a breadboard (or female header on a breakout) so I can easily connect a multimeter to it.
- Lots of single pin 2.54mm Dupont male and female connector wires to make interconnections between male headers.
- Battery holders for 1 and 4 penlights.
- IC sockets.
- Account credentials to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/