# What are the Best Starter Supply Kits?

Tags: kits

I am just getting started out learning electronics and I keep finding myself having to order capacitors and transistors and other parts for simple projects.

What are the best starter sets for a beginner? i.e. who sells a good set of capacitors for a newbie? transistors, resistors, LEDs, etc...

Im interested in both complete sets (that includes different types), as well as individual sets (say, for just capacitors).

Ideally, the kits are weighted toward pieces that you will use more often.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

In answer, I'd try go for the [Basic Prototyping Parts Kit](http://www.elexp.com/pro_bppk.htm) from Electronix Express, and possibly the [supplement](http://www.elexp.com/pro_bpk2.htm) if it has stuff you want.

As a meta-answer, there are a whole bunch of threads on topics like this one.
I propose that we set up a FAQ, dedicated tags, or community wiki/sticky for this kind of question on supplies, stocking, and equipment, including:

- [What is a general set of components for a robotics hacker?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3501/what-is-a-general-set-of-components-for-a-robotics-hacker)
- [Which electronics components should I always have on hand?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/966/which-electronics-components-should-i-always-have-on-hand)
- [Long-lasting electronics items](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/long-lasting-electronics-items)
- [What's the best way to store and categorise resistors/capacitors/ICs/etc?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/whats-the-best-way-to-store-and-categorise-resistors-capacitors-ics-etc)
- [Personal electronics tool kit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/869/personal-electronics-tool-kit)
- [Which equipment for electronics should I always have on hand?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/what-equipment-for-electronics-should-i-always-have-on-hand)
- [Best Electronic Kits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3644/best-electronic-kits)
- and this question, [What are the Best Starter Supply Kits?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3744/what-are-the-best-starter-supply-kits)

Comment: Either that, or ask all the questions that need to be asked here (I think/hope we're getting close), and then mark subsequent questions as duplicates, but that feels mean.

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate of those posts.

I am looking for specific kits, not just lists of individual components that someone can put together themselves.

i.e. kits such as the Electronix Express kit you linked.

Comment: Oh, I should add that they also sell individual resistor/capacitor/inductor/potentiometer kits on the same site.

Comment: "Specific kits" would be a shopping question, which is not allowed.  I'm getting kind of sick of all the "I don't know anything, where should I start?" questions.  Think about what you want to accomplish first, do some research, and then ask specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

SparkFun has a few various types of kits:

- [Inventor's Kit](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9951)
- [Tool Kit](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9466)
- [Arduino Flex Starter Kit](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9952)
- [Sensor Kit](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9383)
- [Robotics Kit - Robo-CIRCLE](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9503)

Answer (score 1):

You can get kits of individual components for pretty cheap on eBay. For example:

- [1000 resistors (50 values with 20 pieces each)](http://cgi.ebay.com/1-4W-Metal-Film-Resistor-Assortmet-kit-set-1000-pcs-/320548786086?cmd=ViewItem&pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4aa2324fa6#ht_3672wt_1036) for $9
- [500 capacitors for $20](http://cgi.ebay.com/21-value-Capacitor-Assortment-Kit-500pcs-0-01-4700uF-/260467530848?cmd=ViewItem&pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3ca5131c60) (21 values with different quantities...more of the cheap ones, less of the expensive ones obviously)

Comment: There's little point in buying them if each bag isn't individually labeled though.  >:(

Comment: To be fair, most of the ones on eBay that I've seen are labeled.  I just bought a boatload of SMD caps/resistors on eBay and they all came labeled.

Comment: @endolith: In my above two links, the first one specifically says "Individually packed and labeled", and the second doesn't specifically say it, but the pictures show a bunch of separate little baggies with values written on them.

Answer (score 1):

[Rapid Electronics](http://www.rapidonline.com/) supplies component kits.

Answer (score 1):

This [Arduino starter kit](http://www.oomlout.co.uk/arduino-experimentation-kit-ardx-p-183.html) from .:oomlout:. is fantastic, it's a really good price and you can buy it with or without an [Arduino Duemilanove](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDuemilanove) (Programmable [micro controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller)) - plus .:oomlout:. is a groovy company too!

Comment: I believe that starter kit is exactly the same as Sparkfun's "Inventor kit", just that this distributor is for the UK.

Comment: Yeah - it's the same kit, it's originally by .:oomlout:. but you can buy them from Sparkfun, Solarbotics, Adafruit and floris. Was using one last weekend at a Howduino event.....they're a fantastic buy.

Comment: See also http://www.bitsbox.co.uk/compkits.html and http://www.bitsbox.co.uk/poundshop.html. Several other shops also sell "GCSE kits" (e.g. Maplin)