# What's an easy way to supply power to a breadboard without using batteries?

Tags: power-supply, breadboard

There are a number of kits available (for example sparkfun's [Breadboard Power Supply USB - 5V/3.3V](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8376) and [Breadboard Power Supply 5V/3.3V](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/114) or Adafruit's [Adjustable breadboard power supply kit -  v1.0](http://adafruit.com/products/184)) but these all come as kits. What is a common and easy of-the-shelf way for a beginner to supply DC power to a breadboard without using batteries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found these breadboard power supplies ([$2.12 or so on ebay.com](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PCS-MB102-Breadboard-Power-Supply-Module-3-3V-5V-For-Arduino-Board-/251073621984?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a75276fe0), shipped) very useful for the purpose described:

[image: Breadboard Power Supply]

Jumper-selected 3.3 and 5 Volt simultaneous outputs from wall-wart, USB or 9 Volt battery.

They have a convenient 2.1 mm barrel jack port on board, besides a power button and an indicator LED. You can choose to have 3.3 Volts on one of the power rail rows of the breadboard, and 5 Volts on the other, something I find especially useful.

As a fellow breadboard user, you might also find two of my answers to other questions on this site, of interest:

- On "[Good Quality Breadboards](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/57976/14004)"
- On "[“Starter Kit for electronics” - What to buy?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/61461/14004)"

Comment: @dumbledad  You're welcome. Also, it's always good to wait a day or so before accepting an answer, in case people from other time zones come up with something better.

Comment: +1 for the time zone tip - I'm usually so pleased I accept immediately!

Comment: @dumbledad I can understand the temptation :-) Of course, you can always come back and accept the answer tomorrow!

Answer (score 5):

Wall wart power supples - cheap, plentiful, just be careful of their output voltage. Many are odd voltages or unregulated (the voltage changes with load) although many are quite usefully designed.

Alternatively, old PC power supplies - Dangerous prototypes do an ATX breakout board, either use one of those or read about how it works & use the information to power your circuit. PC PSU's typically have 12v, 5v, 3v3 available which gives you everything you should need to get started. Just beware that many require a small load (resistor/light bulb) to work properly (the ATX breakout adds this if required).

Comment: Thanks John. How do you connect the barrel connector on the end of the DC wall wart power supply to the breadboard?

Comment: Either cut it off & solder offcut component legs on for easy insertion, or stick a barrel connector on the breadboard.

Comment: An old phone charger will often do.

Answer (score 2):

Really *any* basic power supply would do. For example, I use this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbNNGc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Transformer, rectifier, large capacitor and a variable voltage regulator. You can also split R1 in two (5K and 500R) for extra fine tuning. Gauge the potmeter so you can see the output voltage without measuring.

Comment: Thanks Camil, but I was more after "off-the-shelf" solutions rather than circuit diagrams. Simple instructions on how to connect a shop brought DC power supply to a breadboard would be perfect.

Comment: Build it one time and it is off-the-shelf ;)

Answer (score 1):

I asked some colleagues too and got a couple of interesting answers.

1. Cut a USB power cable and solder on wires that can connect onto header pins in the breadboard. (Not off-the-shelf, but doesn't sound tricky either.)
2. Use a Gadgeteer power module. I have several .Net Gadgeteer kits so this one's easy for me.

Take the Gadgeteer power module (for example [this one from GHI](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/280))

[image: GHI .Net Gadgeteer power module]

Run the Gadgeteer cable from it, but instead of hooking it up with the Gadgeteer mainboard, as one usually would, run it instead to a Gadgeteer extender (like this one) onto which header pins have been soldered.

[image: GHI .Net Gadgeteer Extender module]

(N.B. One manufacturer makes the extender board with the header pins already on, but I cannot find them at present.) The schematic of the power board should say which pins are 5v, 3.3v, and ground, or you can use a multimeter.

Of course this is of little use unless (like us) you have lots of Gadgeteer kit around the office!